# How to call api from ASP.NET razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, razor, web-applications

Just as stated above, I am not sure how to call an `API`.
I have done it using fetch in the example below:

```
fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/patients/add", {
  method: "POST",
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "no-cache",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: postBody
});}
```

But it seems there is a different way of doing things in **Razor view**.
Below is what I have in my `API`:

```
    // GET: api/Patients/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Patient>> GetPatient(int id)
    {
        var patient = await _context.Patient.FindAsync(id);

        if (patient == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return patient;
    }
```

It's just the `GET` made when creating an `API` in `Visual Studio`.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is contradictive to the razor page functionality. I think even if you can, you should not. Just create a Web Api Controller and call it.

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing. I have a Controller in the api called PatientsController.cs and it has all the CRUD language in it. Now I am trying to call it from the separate web application I created. The controller in the api returns the JSON as expected so it works

Comment: Razor pages is sth very different https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio. You can only imagine my confusion and surprise when i saw your question. Please update your title to razor view..

Comment: Also there is a mismatch between your `fetch post` and your `api get`. What is your issue?
It is not clear. Please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing that worked. Thanks for the help guys!

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var options = {};
        options.url = "https://localhost:44381/api/States";
        options.type = "GET";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.success = function (states) {

            states.forEach(function (state) {
                $("#state").append("<option>" + state.stateName + "</option>"
                )
            });
        };

        options.error = function () {
            $("#msg").html("Error while calling the Web API!");
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following ajax call, within a script tag inside the razor page - although this is not best practice - would work as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetPatient", "Patients")",
        data: { id : 1234 },
        success: function(result){
        //do something with result here
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

The second parameter of Url.Action is the Controller Name. This may need to be adapted for yourself.

Comment: Why exactly is it not best practice? @panoskarajohn said to just create a web api controller and call it, I thought thats what I am trying to do. I have a controller called PatientsController.cs in my api. Is that not where it's supposed to go? My api returns the JSON the way it's supposed to.

Comment: @JoshuaDickson That is absolutely fine. I was more saying the bad practice is when you have your JavaScript code directly in your Razor page.